# Conversation Management for Intents in MS Bot framework

Tags: c#, botframework, chatbot, azure-language-understanding

I am using C# MS Bot Framework V4.0 and using LUIS for intent identification. As you aware we are having Dialog classes for managing conversations for a particular intent by using Waterflow dialog etc.. For each and every intent we need to create a dialog class and manage the conversation flow using the same. Or else we can have a standard JSON template and can have a generic Dialog class for handling all conversations based on the flow in that JSON for that identified intent.
But are we having any UI/UX tool for configuring/managing or training the conversation flow of each and every intent like the parent and sub intent concepts present in Dialogflow?
Is that possible in LUIS, because i can see only intent and entity identification in LUIS?
Is there any other way we can achieve that conversation management instead of coding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft is working on an opensource project called MS Bot Composer. Using which we can build our dialogs using just drag and drop. Also it can be connected to LUIS and QnA Maker which few setup. It is in preview mode and will be released soon.

Answer (score 0):

For a "no code" option, you can use [Power Virtual Agents](https://powervirtualagents.microsoft.com/). But it's not directly portable from your coded version, and it is not going to have the same level of capabilities depending on how complex your dialogs are. There's also a separate license for it, though you can sign up for a free trial.